# The Makefile generated by Cmake would not compile the File after compiled success

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors

I generated a makefile by CMake. This makefile works when I run `make` command. However, if after that I edit the source file and run `make` again, then it isn't compiled again.

If I compile the file run make first, it detect some error and stop as usual, once the I fix the error and run make again it could contiunly compile.

I use these command in the root CMakeLists.txt file.

```
ExternalProject_Add(NAME1
    PREFIX NAME1
    SOURCE_DIR 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    )

ExternalProject_Add(NAME2
    PREFIX NAME2
    SOURCE_DIR 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    CMAKE_ARGS 
    DEPENDS NAME1
    )
```

I think whether it is beacuse that I dont add some dependence between the files, some editions will not make the makefile dectect the file has change and then it will not run again.

Comment: "I think whether it is beacuse that I dont add some dependence between the files" - It is impossible to suggest the reason since you don't describe which file you are changing, which code uses that file and so on. Please, prepare [mcve] which would demonstrate your problem.

Comment: what are `NAME1` and `NAME2`? is it part of your project or some external projects?